# Bootstrap - drop downs no longer working online but works perfect in VS Code Live Server

Tags: visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, navbar

I uploaded my website to a new host, Web Host Canada.   I downloaded all the files from the previous host, Hostpapa.ca and then uploaded to the new Host but now the dropdown menus are not working.

[www.FeaterX.com](http://www.FeaterX.com)

However, in VS-Code Live Server everything is working perfectly.

here is the coding I did for the Navbar

```
<!--      Featerx nav bar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent no-gutters pb-5 sticky-top trn">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">            
            <div class="header-title">
              <h4 class="text-center text-light">FeaterX International</h4>
              <h6 class="text-center text-light">- est. 1994 -</h6>
            </div></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-5" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link text-warning" href="http://thekingslandingresort.ca/">
            <h5 class="text-center">The King's Landing Luxury RV Resort</h5>
            </a>
        </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-warning" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLinkConsulting" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <h5 class="text-center"> FX<em>i</em>-Consulting</h5>
            </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-light" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="FXi_Consulting.html">
                <h4 class="text-left">FX<em>i</em>-Consulting</h4>
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="FXi_JobSite_Solutions.html">
                <h4 class="text-left">FX<em>i</em>-JobSite Solutions</h4>
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="FXi_Learning.html">
                <h4 class="text-left">FX<em>i</em>-Learning</h4>
                </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    

    
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-warning" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <h5 class="text-center"> Great Reads</h5>
                    </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-light" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="FeaterX_Articles_Books_Blogs_etc.html">
                <h4 class="text-left">Articles</h4>
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="FeaterX_Books.html">
                <h4 class="text-left">Books</h4>
                </a>
                <!-- <a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="FeaterX_Articles_Books_Blogs_etc.html">
                <h4 class="text-left">Social Media</h4>
                </a> -->
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutters navbutton d-none d-lg-inline">
    <div class="col nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Contact.html">         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
             Contact
         </button>
        </a>
        <a class="LinkedIn" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/roy-cooper-5b9b3988/">
            <img src="images/LI-China-Logo.png" alt="Linked In logo with both english and cantonese characters" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you watching your browser console or network tab? That's fundamental to debugging cases like this.

Comment: forgive me but I am an old man, this is new to me, self taught to write the code and my two websites, not sure what you mean.   I opened up the website online in chrome, microsoft edge and via my android Huawei P30 Pro phone, and the issue is the same.  the Nav button on the mobile does not respond either   .... BTW I love your Avatar,  I grew up on MAD magazines

Answer (score 2):

Your scripts are not loading. They are missing. Recheck their path:

[image]

---

After your first comment I tested again, and now the protocol `HTTP/3` has changed to `HTTP/2` but still missing the files.  Maybe a permissions problem?

This is the new browser console result:

[image]

Comment: Okay not sure why though, I loaded them the same and did not change anything.   I downloaded from them my old host - Hostpapa to my laptop then uploaded them to my new host 'Web Host Canada'.

Comment: the files in file manager in c-panel are all the same as they were on HostPapa

Comment: SOLVED...... oh boy I am an idiot.... the file name for the Java  I put "jss" not "js"......  Thank you very much .... I did say that I am old right?

Comment: You could verify it by your self. If using firefox or chrome just right click hover the page and select "Inspect".

Comment: Great :-)  I am glad to help you.  I see now it runs well.

Comment: Due your old age, let me reminder you to mark the answer as accepted :-D  (jooking... just to avoid more answers)